# How to show ads in android app that fetch from my own server

Tags: android, advertisement-server

I want to show a view in bottom of my application, to show ads, that fetch from my own Linux server.

The **important point** is that i want to have my own control panel in server side. So i **can't** use AdMob, Google Ads SDK, ... or every SDK that doesn't have open source server side panel.

I searched too much, and found many open source project (client and server side), but i'm confused.

1-Whats is publisherId?
2-Can i fetch ads from my own server?

Is there any open source library in both side?(client and server)? Or if there is not, With which opensource library I can fetch ads from my own server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have mentioned you want control over you ad server. Then in this case `Revive-Adserver` is better option. because It takes care of most of the stuffs like ad delivery, conditions, Different Advertising campaigns etc. It have Many features.

for both small or Big business Revive-adserver is suitable. also it is open source.

you can control your ads better way by Defining `gender` or `age` group to whom ad is delivered and also inbuilt Analytics feature is also there, optionally it allow to embed Google Analytics Integration with Banners.

Revive does not have Android SDK for showing ads but As you also want to show your Ads in Android side.  It is easy to show it in your `Android WebView` with some Javascript, CSS and PHP knowledge.(I feel it is easy to setup without the need of Android SDK)

- Create one webpage on your Server side (add some checks for security 
  like it should be accessible from android device only or ios only)
- Paste `Ad Invocation code` on that webpage.
- Call that webpage in your `Android Webview`

You can have a look at documentation provided by them to setup everything, also they have Forum for discussion.

There are many other adservers which have Android SDK provided by them but you will have limited support and also less Features . Some have Premium plans for support or they are not active anymore.

Comment: publisher ID is unique ID which is used in Android SDK for Identification. also openx is the old name of revive adserver but currently  opensource version is Revive Adserver

Comment: Does it have advertiser panel and publisher panel? Is there any demo link? Does it support ad for mobile screen size?

Answer (score 3):

Revive Adserver is the best option for you. There are lots of extensions available for Mobile SDK (iOS/Android).

I would like to recommend mJAX-Mobile-Ads-SDK for iPhone/Android Apps. Kindly check the below URL for more details.
http://www.openxservices.com/mobile-advertising/mJAX-Mobile-Ads-SDK-for-iPhone-Android-Apps.php

You can also check http://www.openxmods.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it for testing or displays, you can try adding a webview in your app and load an iframe in it. That iframe can have your url as 'src' and you can provide 100%, 300px etc kind of dimensions.